# Azure Service Bus Nothing Happens When I Send Message

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have set up an Azure Service Bus and a class using Microsoft's Azure Service Bus documentation as a template.  When I try running my code nothing happens.  No messages are sent to the service bus. I tried breaking it with incorrect queue name and connection string and didn't even get an error.  I am new to Async programming so maybe I am not properly implementing my tasks.

> ```
>     public static async Task SendMessageAsync(string messageToSend)
>     {
>         // create a sender Bus Client
>         ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
>         
>         // create a sender for the queue.
>         ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
>
>         // create a message that we can send. 
>         ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(messageToSend);
>
>         // send the message
>         await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
>         Console.WriteLine($"Sent a single message to the queue: {queueName}");
>
>         await client.DisposeAsync();            
>     }
> ```

Calling this method here:

```
    private void ProcessPerformanceContributionFeed(string[] args, string batchRunId)
    {
        
        var task1 = Task.Run(async() =>  await AzureServiceBusHelper.SendMessageAsync($"Performance Contribution Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}"));
```

The tasks runs (I think?) without any errors or any messages being sent to the Service Bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into this issue is because you're not waiting for the task to complete.

Please change the following line of code:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(async() =>  await AzureServiceBusHelper.SendMessageAsync($"Performance Contribution Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}"));
```

to

```
var task1 = Task.Run(async() =>  await AzureServiceBusHelper.SendMessageAsync($"Performance Contribution Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}"));
task1.Wait();
```

and your problem should be fixed.

More information on Task.Wait can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0.

Comment: Why not just tell them to remove `Task.Run` and call `AzureServiceBusHelper.SendMessageAsync($"Performance Contribution Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}").GetAwaiter().GetResult();`? What's the advantage of keeping an asynchronous method inside of `Task.Run`?

Comment: @Andy - Or go async/await completely :)

Comment: @Andy if I tried that method, I got a warning saying something on the line of ".NET recommends using await Otherwise Code may run to competition".  The reason I cannot make the entire thing async is because this is a micro process in a system of many processes that are not set up for asynchronous.  For now I just want to use the Service Bus for this process as a test.